# Execute a Python script using the command line

Tags: python, syntax-error, program-entry-point

I want to know how to execute a python script using the command line. This is my code in Arithmetic.py:

```
def main(): 
    print 'spam' 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

When I type

```
python Arithmetic.py
```

I get an Syntax Error on the "c"

```
File "ipython-input-11-0770a0dfdadd", line 1
  python Arithmetic.py
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is this __ALL__ your code?

Comment: There is no "c" in the code you pasted.  Are you typing "python Arithmetic.py" into the Python shell?

Comment: Sorry no ideas, as I don't know the exact error message and the complete code

Comment: @BrenBarn might be right, you can't call `python Arithmetic.py` from the python shell. You use that call from `cmd` or `sh`

Comment: @BrenBarn: yep, that's exactly how the syntax error would look if the OP typed it into the IPython shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to type the `python Arithmetic.py` command into an IPython shell.  Instead, make sure you're using your operating system's command prompt.  (You can get out of a Python or IPython shell by typing `exit()`.)

On Windows, the command prompt looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Carter>
```

On Linux, the command prompt looks like this:

```
carter@carters-computer:~$
```

In Mac OS X, it looks like this:

```
Carters-Macbook:~ csande$
```

Answer (score 2):

To invoke your program from within ipython, use `import Arithmetic` (no '.py') in the same directory, followed by `Arithmetic.main()`.  You can use the phrase you're currently trying to run your program from a command shell, without first starting an interpreter.

Comment: Note you can also use ipython's `%run` to run a file from within ipython.